# MySql: indexing all fields of a table to speedup search query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I need to set index to all the fields used for search a text given in search form.

In MySql, Is it possible to set indexes for all the fields of a table for speedup the select query. Is it good practice too?

Comment: Are you talking about full-text searching? It's certainly possible to add indexes for all columns, but it will use lots of memory.

Comment: It will also increase the insert/update/delete time.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes it would. is there any other way for speed query without indexing all the fields. like using view or stored procedure which would I can go for anything else.

Comment: Indexes are the way to speed up queries. You should just index the columns you need to search most often, not all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it it possible to index all columns, but it's no good practice. More indexes maybe speed up your select and slow down insert, update, delete. First, the better way it it to check slow queries with mysql EXPLAIN to see what's going on.